# 'NULL entry' error in MVC4 Edit view option of a MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, detailview

In the implemntation of a Displayview in a `MVC` application I am getting the NULL entry for Parameter error  when I click on Edit option.

Used code for the controller is given below:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ? id, ConferDetal cnfdr) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (ConBitEtities btis = new ConBitEtities())

            {
                btis.Entry(cnfdr).State = EntityState.Modified;
                btis.SaveChanges();
            }
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Scheduler");//view for the controller
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

what is the reason for this error and how to solve this issues?

Comment: can you show your project RouteConfig.cs code

Comment: following is the routeconfig.cs code                                                    
                                                                                                            
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: can you show URL which is calling this Edit ActionResult

Comment: You haven't shown us the right method there must be one that only take one parameter `Edit(int id)` it will be this one you need to make nullable `Edit(int? id)`.

Comment: Thanks Ashley....Got the error....missed the Edit(int? id)!!1

Answer (score 0):

Change your route configuration as shown below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Make sure that your view has the following(similar) ActionLink

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ConfSchedule", new {id = "1"})%>
```

Comment: its Controller not an APIController

Comment: I have given the route configuration code for my project. Is that different? from

Comment: You are not passing id attribute so that you are getting exception

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConferenceID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting an id parameter in your URL but you aren't supplying one.

[image]

Comment: that is what i want to know...?